# Building set 9396 Rescue Helicopter

Tags: technic, instructions

I found an old box with set 9396 “Rescue Helicopter”. I have one problem: If I build the two double wheels at the back according to the instructions, they seem stuck and the wheels cannot be lowered. I found a way to change the design slightly and they move up and down just fine.

Question: If you have the set, am I doing something wrong? Or are there instructions that just don’t work correctly?

The problem are the light gray, yellow, dark grey parts from left to right. According to the instructions they go at some weird angle, I built them side by side.

[image: Original instructions]

[image: Actually built]

Comment: I've built this model many years ago and I had no issue when following the instructions exactly. This is a great model, with 4 motorized functions (assuming you put in the motor) with the landing gear extending and retracting being one of them (front and back wheels simultaneously). I cannot imagine this working correctly if you've built it like you've shown.